# Как сделать так ,чтобы считались все введенные числа?Не понимаю как в конечную сумму добавить первый num

Tags: инспекция-кода

```
    sum = 0
    amount = 0
    num = float(input("Введите цены товаров(0 для выхода): "))
    while num != 0:
       if (num == 0):
          print("Error")
          exit(0)
       num = float(input("Введите цены товаров(0 для выхода): "))
       sum += num
    print("Сумма покупки: ",sum)
```

Comment: Опишите логику работы, раз уж тег "инспекция-кода". У вас написано: ""Введите цены товаров(0 для выхода)" - т.е. 0 - штаный выход, а одновременно при 0 пишется "Error".

Comment: Поменяйте строку, которая перед циклом на `num = None`, например :)  Первый `input` просто не нужен вообще. И не называйте свою переменную `sum`.

Comment: Программа получает число, не равное нулю,потом (по идее) должно складывать со всеми остальными полученными числами. И если введенное число окажется равным нулю, то программа завершится. Но проблема вот в чем: из первой переменной num не берется значение и не вписывается в итоговую sum

Comment: Почему не называть переменную sum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем коде множество проблем.

- Условие `if (num == 0)` никогда не выполняется, т.к. цикл `while` при
  условии `num != 0` остановится сразу же, как `num` получит значение
  `0`.
- Даже если бы условие `if (num == 0)` срабатывало,
  то вы бы получали `SystemExit` благодаря `exit(0)` вместо итоговой суммы, а возможность
  узнать конечную стоимость всей покупки отсутствует вовсе.
- У вас идет конкретное дублирование кода.
- Вы проинициализировали неиспользуемую переменную `amount`.
- Вы заменяете "системную" функцию `sum` на переменную.

Я предлагаю улучшить ваш код до:

```
amount = 0
while price := float(input('Введите цену товара (0 для выхода): ')):
    amount += price
if not amount:
    raise SystemExit('Error')
print(f'Сумма покупки: {amount}')
```

Что касается вашего вопроса, то вы просто не прибавляете к переменной `sum` значение первой `num`.

Comment: Вы не включили проверку на 0 изначальный с выдачей "Error".

Answer (score 1):

Оставаясь в логике вашей программы надо просто присвоить это значение переменной `summ`, да проверку на ошибку вынести за цикл.
Переменную `sum` переименовал - это имя функции в Python, нехорошо её переопределять.

```
num = float(input("Введите цены товаров(0 для выхода): "))
if not num:
    print ("Error")
    exit (0)
summ = num
while num:
   num = float(input("Введите цены товаров(0 для выхода): "))
   summ += num
print("Сумма покупки: ",summ)
```

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)